# Написать функцию вычисление окружноти

Tags: c#

как написать функцию вычисление площади круга ?На Языке программирования с#

Comment: также как и на любом другом языке программирования - ручками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;

class CircleArea
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Площадь круга: S=πrˆ2
        Console.WriteLine("Введите радиус окружности: ");
        double radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double pi = Math.PI;
        double area = pi * (radius * radius);
        Console.WriteLine("Площадь (S=πrˆ2) окружности равна: {0:0.00}", area);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное